# If-else statement for 5 Conditions in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a scenario where I have to match all possible conditions for 5 variables with the if-else statement, the value of variables can be either 0 or 1, for example

```
if($a === 0 && $b === 0 && $c === 0 && $d === 0 && $e === 0) { 
    echo 'case_1';
} else if ($a === 1 && $b === 1 && $c === 1 && $d === 1 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_2';
} else if ($a === 0 && $b === 1 && $c === 1 && $d === 1 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_3';
} else if ($a === 0 && $b === 0 && $c === 1 && $d === 1 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_4';
} else if ($a === 0 && $b === 0 && $c === 0 && $d === 1 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_5';
} else if ($a === 0 && $b === 0 && $c === 0 && $d === 0 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_6';
} else if ($a === 1 && $b === 0 && $c === 0 && $d === 0 && $e === 0) {
    echo 'case_7';
} 

----
----
```

There could be dozens of such conditions and managing it becomes complicated, so I want to know if there is any better and robust method to achieve this?

**Update:**

Variables could be alphanumeric as well,

```
$none = 'none'; // Default value

if($a === $none && $b === $none && $c === $none && $d === $none && $e === $none) { 
    echo 'case_1';
} else if ($a === 1 && $b === 1 && $c === 1 && $d === 1 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_2';
} else if ($a === $none && $b === 1 && $c === 1 && $d === 1 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_3';
} else if ($a === $none && $b === $none && $c === 1 && $d === 1 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_4';
} else if ($a === $none && $b === $none && $c === $none && $d === 1 && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_5';
} else if ($a === $none && $b === $none && $c === $none && $d === $none && $e === 1) {
    echo 'case_6';
} else if ($a === 1 && $b === $none && $c === $none && $d === $none && $e === $none) {
    echo 'case_7';
} 

------
------
```

Comment: can you please post a real example? because this is very strictly based on the order, for example i can associate `00000-> case_0` `00000->case_1` and so on, and so it's not your order, and also, you have not provided any limits of the values of `$a,$b...` so IDK when to stop

Comment: Please check the update in the question, in some case variables value could be different,  none is the default value.

Comment: if there is no logic order in those combinations, than the only solution is the one already shown, that at most helps you to write less code, but believe me that is better if you can find some logic in there, OR AS I ASKED, to post a real scenario!

Comment: My update is the real scenario in my case, 'none' is the default value for the variables, and 1 is the value fetched from the HTML checkbox.

Comment: Does the order makes some sense or it can be changes? for example `00000-> case_0`,  `00001-> case_1`,  `00010-> case_2` is a valid option, or the order must be the same as shown?

Comment: Hmmm...  now the mention of checkboxes.

Comment: it could be in any order.

Comment: @deepak-singh if you model the problem, in terms of a simple positional state problem, you could use something like in my answer below... but without knowing more about your particular use case, It's a little bit of a shot in the dark...

Comment: What do you actually want to do besides `echo 'case_1';`? If we know what you are trying to do, there may be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm trying to think of a slicker way, but for now; you can combine the variables into a string and check:

```
switch($a.$b.$c.$d.$e) {
    case '11111':
        echo 'case_1';
        break;
        
    case '00000':
        echo 'case_2';
        break;
        
    //etc...
}
```

As for your edit, just use variables in the cases:

```
    case $none.$none.$none.$none.$none:
    //or 
    case $none.'1111':
    //etc
```

Comment: I hope that they can have only 0 and 1 as value, that generates already 32 combinations, so with `0,1,2` as possible values, we already have a number to big to manage (3^5)

Comment: ohoh the updates makes the beers even more interesting

Comment: @Berto99 I'll probably delete this in the morning :-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver It seems very interesting let me try if this works for me.

Comment: @AbraCadaver thank you so much, your answer and such use of concatenation gave me an initial idea and I concluded it all in just 8 lines, a lot of time & effort is saved. I will post my answer after some more testing.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, I can only tell you the existence of the [match expression](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/match-expression), but is available only in PHP8:

```
$case = match($a.$b.$c.$d.$e) {
    '00000' => 'case_0',
    '11111' => 'case_1',
    ...
    // default => something,
};
```

That is just a "smaller" `switch`

Comment: thank you for the info, match expression is interesting but as of now I'm on PHP 7.3.x, In future definitely it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well without understanding, what your particular use case is, just that you want to check what essentially equates some sort of encoded state... I took the liberty to demonstrate a fully demonstrated use case.

at the heart of this example is this parseCrumbs function, who's abstract would be something like this...

```php
    function parseCrumbs($crumbs, $tranformer,  $text = '')  {

        // provide a list of methods, to carry out some sort of tranformation, based on positions
        static $places = ['negative', 'thousands', 'hundreds', 'tens', 'ones'];

        if(is_string($crumbs)) 
            $crumbs = str_split($crumbs, 1);

        // Reduce $crumns through transformations...
        foreach ( array_combine( $places, $crumbs ) as $method => $value ){
            if($value) $text .= " " . $tranformer::$method($value, $text);
        }

        return  $text === '' ? '-- empty --' : $text . PHP_EOL;

    }
```

Demonstration of mock use case: Transform a 5 position state string to representing the total count in words...

```php
    class Transformations {

        static public function ones ($count, &$text ) {
            if($count)
                return ($text === '' || $text !== 'Minus ') ? "( {$count} ) Ones" : "and ( {$count} ) Ones";
            return '';
        }

        static public function tens ($count, &$text ) {
            if($count)
                return "( {$count} ) Tens";
            return '';
        }

        static public function hundreds ($count, &$text ) {
            if($count)
                return "( {$count} ) Hundreds";
            return '';
        }

        static public function thousands ($count, &$text ) {
            if($count)
                return "( {$count} ) Thousands";
            return '';
        }

        static public function negative ($count, &$text ) {
            if($count)
                return  'Minus';
            return '';
        }
    }

    function parseCrumbs($crumbs, $translations,  $text = '')  {
        static $places = ['negative', 'thousands', 'hundreds', 'tens', 'ones'];

        if(is_string($crumbs)) 
            $crumbs = str_split($crumbs, 1);

        foreach ( array_combine($places, $crumbs ) as $method => $value ){
            if($value) $text .= " " . $translations::$method($value, $text);
        }

        return  $text === '' ? '-- you need money --' : $text . PHP_EOL;

    }
```

```php
    // These examples use a String to encode the state, 
    // but the parseCrumbs function can also accept an array...

    echo parseCrumbs('00001', Transformations::class); // ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('00011', Transformations::class); // ( 1 ) Tens ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('00111', Transformations::class); // ( 1 ) Hundreds ( 1 ) Tens ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('00111', Transformations::class); // ( 1 ) Hundreds ( 1 ) Tens ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('01111', Transformations::class); // ( 1 ) Thousands ( 1 ) Hundreds ( 1 ) Tens ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('10001', Transformations::class); // Minus ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('10011', Transformations::class); // Minus ( 1 ) Tens ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('10111', Transformations::class); // Minus ( 1 ) Hundreds ( 1 ) Tens ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('10111', Transformations::class); // Minus ( 1 ) Hundreds ( 1 ) Tens ( 1 ) Ones
    echo parseCrumbs('11111', Transformations::class); // Minus ( 1 ) Thousands ( 1 ) Hundreds ( 1 ) Tens ( 1 ) Ones
```

To demonstrate the permutations...

```php
    for( $i = 5000; $i > 0; $i--)
        echo parseCrumbs(str_pad($i, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT), Transformations::class);


    // ( 5 ) Thousands
    // ( 4 ) Thousands ( 9 ) Hundreds ( 9 ) Tens and ( 9 ) Ones
    // ( 4 ) Thousands ( 9 ) Hundreds ( 9 ) Tens and ( 8 ) Ones
    // ... 4996 other permutations
    // ( 1 ) Ones
```

When modeled as above, with ~49 lines of code, depending on your transformations... you have the logic to handle 5000 states...

Obviously your use case, would require customizations, but the "logic" would probably remain just as simple and clear.

---

After reviewing you comments above, I whipped together an example, with an array similar to checkbox type inputs...

```php
    class ShirtOptions {

        public function __construct(){
            $this->options = (object)[];
        }

        public function x_large ( $state ) {
            if ($state) $this->options->shirt_size = "x_large";
        }

        public function xx_large ( $state ) {
            if ($state) $this->options->shirt_size = "xx_large";
        }

        public function xxx_large ( $state ) {
            if ($state) $this->options->shirt_size = "xxx_large";
        }

        public function small ( $state ) {
            if ($state) $this->options->shirt_size = "small";
        }

        public function customPrinting ( $state ) {
            if($state){
                $this->options->custom_printing = true;
            } else {
                $this->options->custom_printing = false;
            }
        }

        public function templateID ( $state ) {
            if($state){
                $this->options->template_id = $state;
            }
        }

        public function parseOptions( $params ){
            static $options = [ "x_large", "xx_large", "xxx_large", "small", "customPrinting", "templateID" ];

            if(is_string($params))
                $params = str_split($params, 1);

            foreach ( array_combine( $options, $params ) as $option => $value )
                if($value) $this->$option($value);

            return $this;
        }

        public function to_json(){
            return json_encode($this->options, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
    }
```

```php
    echo (new ShirtOptions())->parseOptions([1,0,0,0,1,475])->to_json();
    {
        "shirt_size": "x_large",
        "custom_printing": true,
        "template_id": 475
    }
```